# winsock recv returning 0 without shutdown from peer, different behavior from when compiling for console

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1, winsock

I'm having an issue with winsock on windows 8.1 where recv keeps returning 0 randomly. I'm running both client and server on the same machine (thus all traffic is pointed at the loopback address) and i have breakpoints on any statement on both client and server which would shut down the sockets. But when the issue occurs the server is still operating normally, and hasn't shutdown anything, while the client has hit a breakpoint that only triggers on recv returning 0 or less.

The client keeps returning 0 from recv randomly (although always at the same point in my code) when the server VS 2013 project is set to compile as a windows program (rather than a console, in order to make it produce no window, it's supposed to be silent running). The bug doesn't seem to occur when i compile the server as a console application, as I've been debugging the program in that mode and only come across this issue when i switched compilation settings.

Is there any way to launch a console window when compiling as a windows application so i can see any debug statements?

Does winsock behave differently when compiling for the console vs compiling for a windows application?

Why would the client's recv return 0, when I've not sent a shutdown signal from the server?

My code, ask if there's any more you need:

Client

```cpp
void recvLoop()
{
    int recievedBytes = 1;
    while (running && recievedBytes > 0)
    {
        WORD dataSize;
        WORD dataType;
        int recievedBytesA = ConnectSock.Recieve(&dataSize, sizeof(WORD));
        if (recievedBytesA <= 0)
        {
            closing = true; //breakpoint set here
            attemptKillThreads();
            continue;
        }
        int recievedBytesB = ConnectSock.Recieve(&dataType, sizeof(WORD));
        if (recievedBytesB <= 0)
        {
            closing = true; //breakpoint set here
            attemptKillThreads();
            continue;
        }

        unique_ptr<char[]> data(new char[dataSize]);
        int recievedBytesC = ConnectSock.Recieve(data.get(), dataSize);
        if (recievedBytesC <= 0)
        {
            closing = true; //breakpoint set here - Always triggers here
            attemptKillThreads();
            continue;
        }

       //use the received data.....

    }
}
```

When this breaks recievedBytesA = 2, recievedBytesB = 2, recievedBytesC = 0, dataType = 0, dataSize = 0

ConnectSock is a global of type ConnectSocket. here is its Recieve()

```cpp
int ConnectSocket::Recieve(void *recvbuf, int recvbuflen)
{
    if (sock != INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        int i = recv(sock, (char *)recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        if ((i == SOCKET_ERROR))
        {
            int err = 0;
            err = WSAGetLastError();
            if (err != WSAEINTR)
            {
                //ignore WSAEINTR as that's likely to be because of a shutdown complating a bit awkwardly
                cout << "error: " << err << endl;
            }
        }

        return i;
    }
    return -2;
}
```

Server:

```cpp
void sendLoop()
{
    int bytessent = 0;
    QueuePack tosend;
    while (running)
    {
        tosend = sendQueue.Dequeue();
        if (tosend.packType == QueuePack::EXIT || tosend.packType == 0 || tosend.dSize == 0)
        {
            attemptKillThreads();
            continue;
        }
        bytessent = Connection->SendData(&tosend.dSize, sizeof(WORD));
        //cout used to see what exactly is being sent, even if it is garbage when converted to text
        cout << tosend.dSize << endl;
        cout << bytessent << endl;
        if (bytessent <= 0)
        {
            attemptKillThreads();
            continue;
        }
        bytessent = Connection->SendData(&tosend.packType, sizeof(WORD));
        cout << tosend.dSize << endl;
        cout << bytessent << endl;
        if (bytessent <= 0)
        {
            attemptKillThreads();
            continue;
        }
        bytessent = Connection->SendData(tosend.bufferPtr(), tosend.dSize);
        cout << tosend.bufferPtr() << endl;
        cout << bytessent << endl;
        if (bytessent <= 0)
        {
            attemptKillThreads();
        }
    }

    if (Connection->shutdownSock(SD_SEND) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        Connection->closeSock();
    }
}
```

SendData is literally a wrapper for send that uses a reinterpret_cast

```cpp
int SendData(void * writeBuffer, int bufferSize)
{
    return send(SocketManager.clientSocket, reinterpret_cast<char *>(writeBuffer), bufferSize, 0);
}
```

sendQueue is a Bounded blocking queue that holds QueuePacks

QueuePacks are used to transfer data, it's size and what kind of data it is between threads. both Client and server use this as it allows me to make sure data gets to the right thread on the client

Queuepack has 2 public variables packType and dSize of type WORD.

```cpp
QueuePack::QueuePack() : packType(UND), dSize(0)
{
        int h = 0; //debug statement to break on - never gets hit after initial collection construction occurs
}

QueuePack::QueuePack(const WORD type, WORD size, char * data) : packType(type), dSize(size)
{
    //debug test and statement to break on
    if (size == 0 || type == 0)
    {
        int h = 0; //breakpoint - never gets hit
    }

    dSize = (dSize < 1 ? 1 : dSize);
    _buffer = make_unique<char[]>(dSize);
    memcpy(_buffer.get(), data, dSize);
}

QueuePack::QueuePack(QueuePack &other) : packType(other.packType), dSize(other.dSize)
{
    //debug test and statement to break on
    if (other.dSize == 0 || other.packType == 0)
    {
        int h = 0; //breakpoint - never gets hit
    }

    if (&other == this)
    {
        return;
    }
    _buffer = make_unique<char[]>(dSize);
    other.buffer(_buffer.get());
}

QueuePack QueuePack::operator= (QueuePack &other)
{
    // check for self-assignment
    if (&other == this)
    {
        return *this;
    }
    // reuse storage when possible
    if (dSize != other.dSize)
    {
        _buffer.reset(new char[other.dSize]);
        dSize = other.dSize;
    }
    packType = other.packType;
    other.buffer(_buffer.get());
    return *this;
}

QueuePack::~QueuePack()
{
}

HRESULT QueuePack::buffer(void* container)
{
    try
    {
        memcpy(container, _buffer.get(), dSize);
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        return E_FAIL;
    }
    return S_OK;
}

char * QueuePack::bufferPtr()
{
    return _buffer.get();
}
```

Comment: Well, you spelt 'receive' incorrectly, but I'm guessing that's not what you wanted to hear:)

Comment: You are aware that 'recv(sock, (char *)recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);' will not necessarily return recvbuflen, even if successfull?

Comment: @MartinJames  I'd expect at least a byte back. as i thought that if there was nothing to return, recv would block, thus the only way it'd get 0 as a return value is if there is a shutdown signal. My spelling is atrocious without the aid of a spellchecker, I'll have to fix that, thanks.

Comment: @ForceGaia: You are getting a return value of 0 because you are setting `recvbuflen` to 0 to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When this breaks recievedBytesA = 2, recievedBytesB = 2, **recievedBytesC = 0**, dataType = 0, **dataSize = 0**

You are calling `ConnectSock.Recieve()` when `dataSize` is 0.  There is nothing to read, so `Receive()` reports that 0 bytes were read.

You need to add a check for that condition:

```
unique_ptr<char[]> data(new char[dataSize]);
if (dataSize != 0) // <-- add this
{
    int recievedBytesC = ConnectSock.Recieve(data.get(), dataSize);
    if (recievedBytesC <= 0)
    {
        closing = true;
        attemptKillThreads();
        continue;
    }
}
```

Your code is also assuming that `Recieve()` reads all bytes that are requested, it is not handling the possibility that `recv()` may return fewer bytes.  So you need to make `Recieve()` call `recv()` in a loop to guarantee that everything requested is actually read:

```
int ConnectSocket::Recieve(void *recvbuf, int recvbuflen)
{
    if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
        return -2;

    char *buf = static_cast<char *>(recvbuf);
    int total = 0;

    while (recvbuflen > 0)
    {
        int i = recv(sock, buf, recvbuflen, 0);
        if (i == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            int err = WSAGetLastError();
            if (err != WSAEINTR)
            {
                //ignore WSAEINTR as that's likely to be because of a shutdown complating a bit awkwardly
                cout << "error: " << err << endl;
            }
            return -1;
        }

        if (i == 0)
        {
            cout << "disconnected" << endl;
            return 0;
        }

        buf += i;
        recvbuflen -= i;
        total += i;
    }

    return total;
}
```

Same with `SendData()`, as `send()` may return fewer bytes than requested:

```
int SendData(void * writeBuffer, int bufferSize)
{
    if (SocketManager.clientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
        return -2;

    char *buf = static_cast<char *>(writeBuffer);
    int total = 0;

    while (bufferSize > 0)
    {
        int i = send(SocketManager.clientSocket, buf, bufferSize, 0);
        if (i == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            int err = WSAGetLastError();
            if (err != WSAEINTR)
            {
                //ignore WSAEINTR as that's likely to be because of a shutdown complating a bit awkwardly
                cout << "error: " << err << endl;
            }
            return -1;
        }

        buf += i;
        bufferSize -= i;
        total += i;
    }

    return total;
}
```

Comment: I see your point, didn't consider that would actually happen, i thought a socket error would occur. The thing is that before then it's reading in 2 WORDs worth of 0 into order to get to that situation. and the server shouldn't be sending this data (or i can't find where it's sending this)

Comment: and why would changing the compilation settings cause this difference?

Comment: What is stopping the server from sending a data message whose `dataSize` value is 0?  Nothing.  This communicate protocol allows that possibility, so you have to account for it. Maybe the protocol really does have 0-length messages defined that you simply have not seen yet. Either way, your code needs to protect itself. As for the compilation settings, they have *NO EFFECT WHATSOEVER* on how a socket operates. The socket API exists in an external DLL, it has no concept of how your code is compiled.

Comment: if you look at the top of the `sendloop()` method i check to see if the type or size are 0, and breakpoint just after it. This breakpoint has never been hit. so i can't fathom when the server is sending this, as by all rights the SERVER should die before it sends a size of zero.

Comment: and as for the compilation settings, that's what i thought too. so as a result i can't fathom why this error only occurs when i have this compiled as windows application. I defined the protocol I'm using: send size, send type, send data, and there's no case where the server should construct anything with 0 for the type or size

Comment: On the receiving size, you were not initializing the `WORD`s before reading them, and not handling the case where `recv()` returns fewer bytes than requested. On the sending side, you were not handling the case where `send()` returns fewer bytes than requested. So it is likely that you were ending up with incomplete values that just happened to equal 0.  Did you even try the code I gave you yet? Have you seen the problem happen since? This is socket programing 101 kind of stuff, you need these kinds of loops when using `recv()` and `send()` for TCP communications.

Comment: While i was replying to your comments i wasn't at my desk, i was just confused as to why my breakpoints weren't being hit for the issues i was having when what you were asking should trigger them. but yes this program is my first time using sockets, so I am making errors worthy of failing sockets 101. the code has been working thus far (i'm tryign my best and the error jsut isn't reappearing), I'm still bewildered as to why this bug only reared it's head after i switched compilation settings